# Changing image src on button click

Tags: javascript, string, image, onclick

I have a *holding page* for a site Under Construction.

There is an image and a box with a button. on clicking the button I want the image to change.

There will be collections of images with the same name plus a subscript 
(eg:  TG-img-**01**.jpg).
Idea is to increment the subscript.

Not used JavaScript for 15 years,  so looking for examples of how it can be done.

cheers.

Comment: What have you tried? Post some code... Even if it's bad... It's easy to get answers here, but it's impossible to help you as your post is stated

Comment: improved formatting and grammar

Answer (score 3):

Given the tag is javascript and not jQuery I would favour a solution that meets that requirement. In that case:

```js
let counter = 0; // declared in global scope
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
     counter++; // increment this instead of rand int so it's 0,1,2 etc
     buildimg = `TG-img-${counter}.jpg`;
     document.querySelector('#imageID').setAttribute('src', buildimg);
      document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = buildimg;
    });
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
<img id="imageID" src=""/>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Hi  ...  sorry for delayed response and  thanks for the suggested solution, 

However,  I cannot see how the random number will help ... 
(1)   files are in the image folder,  cannot display something that isn't available. 
(2)  was thinking of something similar, where "String manipulation" extracts the digits in the filename ...  ...  ?

Comment: the random number is just for if you have, say 10 images that you want to pick one of, and your file names are sequential then it will just pick one. you could alternatively just have a global counter variable and increment that. or are you saying you don't know what the file names will actually be?

Comment: What is a Global variable/counter ? Sounds like it might be ServerSide code    How is it set up and changed ? 
With that sort of thing, the string manipulation I mentioned would not be needed (Filenames are all the same, except for the number). 
.

Comment: I've edited the snippet to show what I mean. global just in the js scope, so in the window scope. just increment it to go through all files. could then add after the counter++ and if(counter>images count) {counter = 1;}

Comment: Hi,   Thanks for that.   So it will all be "on the page"   index.html  and  ppMain.css  ?

Got to try and get the Grid Layout sorted.  Seemed so close with CSS Layout,  now it's quite badly messed up.  Even the Google-font is not being styled.   

Is there any way to ask people to look at what I've done and offer advice ? 
They seem to be ignoring the current question. 

Can attachments be uploaded on here ? 


layout

Comment: It can go straight in the html page, or a separate js one. that's up to you. You can't upload attachments, but you can use something like jsfiddle or codepen to put in html, css, and js. People won't give much help if you don't follow the [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Explain what you want, show what you've tried, and state the problem you have.

Answer (score 2):

Try this below sample code.

```
<script>
 function pictureChange()
  {
   document.getElementById("theImage").src="img02.png";
  }
</script>

<body>
 <img id="theImage" src="img01.png">
 <p><input type="button" id="theButton" value="click me!" 
    onclick="pictureChange()"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi   ...  sorry for delay and thanks for responding..  
The ideas in your suggestion seem to fit my problem,  but wonder if more "string manipulation" could be used to separate the digits in the filename, then increment ?

Answer (score 0):

i just giving random number for your image increment.
so this is just changing img source whenever you click button randomly generated number with your image name like **TG-img-01.jpg**
if you dont understand this let me know glad to help you

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  randint = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  buildimg = 'TG-img-' + randint + '.jpg' 
  $('div > span').text('TG-img-' + randint);
  $('div > img').attr('src', buildimg);
  console.log(buildimg);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>imagine its like picture with TG-img-01.jpg</span>
  <img src='https://www.askideas.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Free-Online-Photos1.jpg'>
</div>
<button>
change
</button>
```

Comment: Don't forget to add .jpg to the image source: buildimg = 'TG-img-' + randint + '.jpg'

Comment: Sorry,  but a random number is not usable  -  has to be a 2-digit number that matches the available image filenames. Not likely to be more than 20. 
Images would normally be held locally.

First image seen would be set in the index.html file.

Which part of the script "refreshes" the image in the window ?

Comment: Dude first you are so late reply of this answer, second why you just cant change random number to increment number

Comment: Mainly because this is a hobby, not a jobby.   I'm retired and have other things on the go.   ...  Like I said,  it has been a long time since I used JS so most of it is forgotten, along with ASP frameworks.